# Why passing a string to URI throws exception?

Tags: java, url, uri

I have a code like this :

```
String previousUrl = "http://localhost:8080/abc.html?xyz=hbkbkj|kjbjkbkj kjbkj";
URL url = new URL(previousUrl);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
```

Now this code works perfectly. And i get the desired URI.

But if I pass the previousUrl to URI constructor then it throws exception. I want to know the reason.

```
String previousUrl = "http://localhost:8080/abc.html?xyz=hbkbkj|kjbjkbkj kjbkj";
URI uri = new URI(previousUrl);
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI(java.lang.String)

Comment: Please Show the exception!

Comment: URISyntaxException : This exception.

Comment: Just find a way to URI encode it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already tells you the reason! There's an invalid character in the url:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 41: http://localhost:8080/abc.html?xyz=hbkbkj|kjbjkbkj kjbkj
```

So the character `|` can't be processed! Therefore you'll have to create an URL before passing the information to the URI constructor (like you already did successfully)

---

You could also try to replace all the characters that can't be processed with their `%` equivalent:

```
new URI(previousUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20").replaceAll("\\|", "%7C"));
```

But you'll have to add more of these replacements every time you meet a new caracter that can't be processed!

Comment: URI constructor will encode my special characters. Right?. Then passing the url without encoding should also work. Am i going wrong?

Comment: @Asish well no that's exactly the problem. The URI constructor doesn't encode the special characters. So you'll either have to do that by hand (see my edit) or use the URL way...

Comment: But passing the URL objects to the URI constructor works fine even if we have special characters. Thats why i thought URI constructors encodes the special characters.

Comment: Well it does when if you take the constructor with 5 String parameters, but not if you take the constructor with 1 String parameter! You're right there!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i get it.